# Echo before the output of the awk command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, terminal, sh

I need to know how to add this line before each output of the `awk` commands. I also need to add how much disk space has been used by the user in their home directory. I have no idea how to combine them guys.

This is how I list users with their home directory.

```
awk -F":" '{print $6}' /etc/passwd | sort | grep /home
```

The output is:

```
/home/testuser
/home/anonsec
```

My desired output is:

```
Home Directory: /home/testuser
Disk Space Used (KB): 23342 KB

Home Directory: /home/anonsec
Disk Space Used (KB): 23342 KB
```

Comment: Any change `du -sh /home/*` would solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks Thomas you're great! But how can I output the format above? Do you have any idea? Thanks Again Thomas :)

Comment: You can drop the use of `grep` by doing `awk -F":" '/home/{print $6}' /etc/passwd | sort`

Comment: Thanks Sudo, how do can I insert the "du -sh" to display the size. My idea is to combine it with "awk -F":" '/home/{print $6}' /etc/passwd | sort" to show the sapce used. Great help man. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
for i in `awk -F":" '{print $6}' /etc/passwd | sort | grep /home`;  do
        echo "Home Directory:" $i
        echo "Disk Space Used (KB):" `du -s $i |cut -f1`
        echo ""
done
```

You might want or need to improve it a bit if you have some things in `/etc/passwd` that you are not interested in.

Comment: This is what i'm talking about. THANKS SUDO.

Comment: Note this isn't my answer it's @user1685841 I just fixed the formatting. I wouldn't do it like this.. hence my actual answer.

Comment: So thanks to you both Sudo and @user1685841 because you helped me alot. :)

Answer (score 4):

```bsh
$ du -s /home/* | awk '{print "Home Directory:",$2,"\nDisk Space Used",$1"\n"}'

Home Directory: /home/luser 
Disk Space Used 42222768
```